# CORS error in Safari, not in Chrome

Tags: cors, xmlhttprequest

I am building a file uploader,
using [Vue Dropzone](https://rowanwins.github.io/vue-dropzone/) on the frontend,
and custom PHP on the backend.

My frontend script is sending a request with following headers:

> **Request headers**
>   POST /jobimport HTTP/1.1
>   Host: myurl
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Content-Length: 765309
>   Origin: http://localhost:8080
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.162 Safari/537.36
>   Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----
>   WebKitFormBoundaryhaaAoTz2J5iipi3M
>   Accept: application/json
>   Cache-Control: no-cache
>   X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
>   Referer: http://localhost:8080/import
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
>   Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,nl;q=0.8,de;q=0.7,fr;q=0.6

In my .htaccess file on the backend, I have added the following lines:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*"
```

When using Chrome, the file uploads without problems.
When looking at the request headers, I even see the following:

> **Response headers**
>   (...)
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
>   (...)

However, when using Safari, the upload fails, and I get the following error:

> Failed to load resource: Request header field Cache-Control is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
>   XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://myurl. Request header field Cache-Control is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

I don't understand how this works in Chrome, but not in Safari.

Comment: I guess this is because Chrome supports using `*` in Access-Control-Allow-Headers to mean “any header name” while Safari does not. So to make it work in Safari, you’d need to explicitly list each header name you want to allow — for example, Cache-Control

Comment: @sideshowbarker is correct. The ability to use `*` for `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` is recent, and it has not been implemented by all browsers yet.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The comments by @sideshowbarker and @roryhewitt are correct,
Safari indeed doesn't support a wildcard `*` for `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`.
I listed all headers explicitly instead of using a wildcard, and now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If parent domain URL is in https, you must call the ajax URL also in https. If not, not use https. Hope this will help